# Debian bookworm installation software raid grub fails with dummt error

Tags: software-raid, debian-bookworm

On a server I'm trying to install Debian Bookworm with software RAID1 with three disks. I'm following this [guide](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/SoftwareRaidRoot). Three disks have been configured to use RAID and I've setup the RAID1 device as in the screenshot and a Volume Group. Then I added three partitions, one ext4, one for EFI (that's the ESP partition) and a swap partition.

[image: Partition layout]

This all goes great until the installer wants to install Grub and there is a fatal error.

[image: Fatal error installing grub]

I've also tried without the LVM but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I also tried https://tweenpath.net/configure-debian-software-raid-1-installation/ but got the same effect

Comment: See the 4-th console for the output. Ctrl-Alt-F4 or Ctrl-A,4.

Comment: The error is: Failed to register the EFI boot entry: Bad address

Comment: You can't put ESP on LVM because UEFI locate ESP and it may not operate LVM volumes. You must add ESP partition before LV partition.

Comment: I asked a similar question a week ago and was helped:
https://serverfault.com/questions/1143899/debian-12-bookworm-installing-a-software-raid-1-fails-with-grub-error